# How to control order of device loading during startup?

Tags: 13.04, kernel, hardware, dmesg, trackpoint

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad E420s. I am having a problem with the timing of device loading during startup. I assume this was always happening, but I did not realize it was an issue until I switched to an SSD and my system began starting up much quicker.

The primary issue is that the TrackPoint does not get loaded until well after the desktop loads. This means that I am left with an unresponsive cursor, unless I use the touchpad or an external mouse.

Here is the relevant part of the dmesg output

```
[   10.969765] init: anacron main process (1305) killed by TERM signal
[   11.055177] init: plymouth-stop pre-start process (1934) terminated with status 1
[   15.895979] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation
[   15.896051] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -101
[   16.372336] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation
[   16.372429] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -101
[   19.313093] device-mapper: ioctl: Unable to rename non-existent device, cryptswap1_unformatted to cryptswap1
[   19.415130] show_signal_msg: 51 callbacks suppressed
[   19.415136] empathy[2481]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007fff9e299128 error 14 in empathy[400000+40000]
[   20.596623] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.0, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xd001a3/0x940300/0x120c00, board id: 1719, fw id: 783906
[   20.596630] psmouse serio1: synaptics: serio: Synaptics pass-through port at isa0060/serio1/input0
[   20.681736] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input11
[   26.222684] psmouse serio2: alps: Unknown ALPS touchpad: E7=10 00 64, EC=10 00 64
[   32.464680] psmouse serio2: trackpoint: IBM TrackPoint firmware: 0x0e, buttons: 3/3
[   32.887796] input: TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/input/input12
```

As you can see, the TrackPoint is not loaded as a device until over 30 seconds after boot. Is there anyway to change this loading order, or to explicitly load the trackpoint so it becomes responsive sooner?

Answer (score 0):

This may be of interest. Boot-Up Manager.

This App allows you to give priority to one process over another when loading.

[image]

Comment: any idea what I'd be looking for in here? I searched for psmouse, but that isn't there. I assume it's something in udev, but I don't really understand how udev works quite yet...

Comment: Hmm! I'm in the same stage of learning as you are, sorry I have no idea. I imagine you have searched for Synaptics

Answer (score 0):

afaik, init is what controls the loading order during bootup.
you should check the /etc/init and the /etc/init.d/README file. it gives a clue as to when a process is started. then you can look for the relevant mouse driver in your case.

But, it's unsafe to screw around with init.d or inittab!
I guess the comment above gives you a safer option.